# Found more than one default KieBase

Tags: java, drools, jbpm, kie

I have the following error (warning) in the server.log:

10:07:18,262 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieProject] (default task-6) Found more than one default KieBase: disabling all. KieBases will be accessible only by name
10:07:18,263 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieProject] (default task-6) Found more than one default StatelessKieSession: disabling all. StatelessKieSessions will be accessible only by name
10:07:18,263 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieProject] (default task-6) Found more than one default KieSession: disabling all. KieSessions will be accessible only by name

I believe it could be related to the issue I am facing - all requests are accepted one by one, by Kie server API, however I need multi-threading.
In order to do that, I have tried to create one Kie Base in the Business Central and 2 different Stateless Kie Sessions for this particular project. I couldn't deploy the project in that case (error I get  java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find a default KieSession)

Anyone had this issue before?
Note - this project has dependencies to 2 other projects. Also the runtime strategy is "Per request".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, if you've created two KieSession why it says there are two Kie Bases?

Comment: Can you share your config (kmodule.xml)?

Answer (score 0):

For all people having this issue, here is the reason - there is a bug in the version 7.0.
Reference - https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DROOLS-1740?page=com.jsoft.jira.plugins.jira-slack%3Aslack-tabpanel&_sscc=t
It is resolved, but NOT for all 7.x versions (and of course, not in the one I am using)
The full list can be seen here -https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/commit/1c2a4eb2924f4942e31e611f095f1223ee2fb5cf.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This should not be an answer to your question as jira says the issue was resolved back in 2017. And the change was about to "keep the default of the top level kmodule" (I understand it as one must be chosen as a prime and it should work)

Comment: It is solved, but not in the version I am using (you can check the list of the versions which have the solution included on the Jira ticket)